# Issue in sending SMS via sp_OAMethod in SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql-server

I am using below given procedure to send SMS from SQL Server. It's working fine till yesterday night.

But, today I am getting following error: -

> -2146697212 
>   Msg 50000, Level 16, State 1, Procedure pr_SendSmsSQL, Line 61
>   sp_OAMethod Send FAILED!

I added "sp_OAGetErrorInfo" to know the exact error then it shows me below given message: -

> Error Source Description
>   msxml3.dll Unable to connect to the target server.

Please guide how to solve this issue. The same code is running properly on another SQL Server.

Stored procedure code : -

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

/* 
Purpose : To send SMS from SQL. 

declare @sResponse as varchar(1000) 
exec pr_SendSmsSQL '1234567891','This Is a Test SMS From SQL Server - Regards, BSethi24','' 
print @sResponse 

*/ 
ALTER Procedure [dbo].[pr_SendSmsSQL] 
@MobileNo varchar(12), 
@smstext as varchar(300), 
@sResponse varchar(1000) OUT 
as 
BEGIN 

Declare @iReq int,@hr int 
Declare @sUrl as varchar(500) 
DECLARE @errorSource VARCHAR(8000)
DECLARE @errorDescription VARCHAR(8000) 



-- Create Object for XMLHTTP 
EXEC @hr = sp_OACreate 'Microsoft.XMLHTTP', @iReq OUT 
print @hr 
if @hr <> 0 
Raiserror('sp_OACreate Microsoft.XMLHTTP FAILED!', 16, 1) 


set @sUrl='http://122.22.12.12/smsportal/sendsms.aspx?usr=test&pass=test&senderid=BSethi24&mobileno=#MobNo#&messagetext=#Msg#' 


set @sUrl=REPLACE(@sUrl,'#MobNo#',@MobileNo) 
set @sUrl=REPLACE(@sUrl,'#Msg#',@smstext) 

print @sUrl 
-- sms code start 


EXEC @hr = sp_OAMethod @iReq, 'Open', NULL, 'GET', @sUrl, true 
print @hr 
if @hr <> 0 
Raiserror('sp_OAMethod Open FAILED!', 16, 1) 

EXEC @hr = sp_OAMethod @iReq, 'send' 
select @iReq
print @hr 
if @hr <> 0 
Begin 
EXEC sp_OAGetErrorInfo @iReq, @errorSource OUTPUT, @errorDescription OUTPUT
SELECT [Error Source] = @errorSource, [Description] = @errorDescription
Raiserror('sp_OAMethod Send FAILED!', 16, 1) 
end 
else 
Begin
EXEC @hr = sp_OAGetProperty @iReq,'responseText', @sResponse OUT 
print @hr

insert into s_SmsLog (Id,Mobile_No,SMSText,SMSResponse,Created_By,Created_Date,Modified_By,Modified_Date) 
values(0,@MobileNo,@smstext,@sResponse,'System',GETDATE(),null,null) 
End
```

Answer (score 0):

The stored procedure should just write to the queue table.
The external application should manage the process from there, also via stored procedures.

If the requirement justifies a more scalable solution, consider using Service Broker.